# sortWith using basic character comparison fails for some strings

Tags: java, scala, sorting

I want to apply a custom sorting `comparator` as follows:

```
 myString.sortWith{ case (c1,c2) => c1.compareTo(c2) <= 0}
```

This *should* sort the characters of the string by their codepoint values.

However it does not always work..  Consider a simple string `cab312`:

```
val str = "cab312"

str.sortWith{ case (c1,c2) => c1.compareTo(c2) <= 0}
res0: String = 123abc
```

That works fine.  Consider a more complex string:

```
scala> val str = "TOADS POOLS hoppin good service & repair"
str: String = TOADS POOLS hoppin good service & repair

scala> str.sortWith{ case (c1,c2) => c1.compareTo(c2) <= 0}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
  at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)
  at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516)
  at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441)
  at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
  at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.sorted(SeqLike.scala:648)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.sorted(StringOps.scala:29)
  at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.sortWith(SeqLike.scala:601)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.sortWith(StringOps.scala:29)
  ... 32 elided
```

So .. we get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

What is going on here? How can the same `comparator` both succeed and fail..  Is this a bug in the `timsort` - and in any case is there a workaround?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  Please read more carefully the other entry:  for that one the comparator provided was not transitive. Whereas for the above case it is.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't see how this is a duplicate of the linked question. Java's comparator produces signed integers, whereas Scala's `sortWith` requires one boolean. It was exactly this boolean that was counter-intuitive. If the OP used comparator-like `Ordering` instead, the problem wouldn't have occurred at all.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There is nowhere in that other question/answer mentioning the nuance of integer comparisons needing to be `<` and not `<=` .  It is a "liberal" decision to close this question.

Comment: Huh... Apparently, I can un-dupehammer it single-handedly... Nice to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states unambiguously that `sortWith` expects a single function `lt` which returns `true` if and only if the first operand *preceeds* (is *strictly **L**ess **T**han*) the second operand:

> **lt** the comparison function which tests whether its first argument precedes its second argument in the desired ordering.

Your `c1.compareTo(c2) <= 0` returns true for elements that are equal, and therefore violates the contract of `lt`. Changing `<=` to `<` eliminates the issue:

```
str.sortWith{ case (c1,c2) => c1.compareTo(c2) < 0}
//"      &ADLOOOPSSTacdeeeghiiinoooppprrrsv"
```

Comment: Nice catch!  So the reason it worked with the first string is that there were no character duplicates.

Comment: @javadba I think you should be able to brute-force an example where there are duplicates, but no exception is thrown. It could happen that the algorithm doesn't run into any invalid states even with duplicate characters and invalid `lt`.